# python не находит модули из dist-packages

Tags: python, debian

Debian, python 2.7

Поставил модуль, но питон его не видит, а ipython - находит. Расследование показало, что все внешние модули в `\usr\local\lib\python2.7\dist-packages`, a sys.path в питоне

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 11 2015, 09:39:24)
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

ipython

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 14 2014, 11:57:14)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 3.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import sys; print sys.path
['', '/usr/local/bin', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions', '/root/.ipython']
```

Что делать?

Edit: у меня 2 версии питона - 2.7.10 (из исходников) и 2.7.3. Поможет если удалить один из них?

Edit 2: причина найдена, дальше [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439435/%D0%95%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/439449)

Comment: А python ставился из репозитория или из исходников? Во втором случае, вполне закономерно, что используется `site-packages` вместо `dist-packages` - ["What is the difference between dist-packages and site-packages?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387928/whats-the-difference-between-dist-packages-and-site-packages). Попробуйте воспользоваться этим ответом: ["How to globally modify the default PYTHONPATH (sys.path)?"](http://superuser.com/a/247649/424804). Также есть вариант поставить пакет в `site-packages`.

Comment: @soon отредактировал

Comment: Насчет того, чтобы удалять один из них - сами смотрите. Если Вам нужен именно 2.7.10, то проще настроить `sys.path`. Либо же, можно запускать скрипт с указанием интерпритатора питона (посмотрите в дректории `bin` какие именно исполняемые файлы за какую версию питона отвечают).

Comment: @soon как я понял, python и pip от разных питонов. Наверно проще будет указать нужный pip. Но наверно было бы вернее удалить лишний - так бы я сделал на винде.

Comment: Python, начиная с 2.7.9 идет вместе с `pip`. Попробуйте выполнить `python -m pip install <pkg_name>` (при условии, что `python` - это 2.7.10), он должен поставить пакет в нужную директорию

Comment: А вообще, может быть Вам имеет смысл посмотреть в сторону [virtual environments](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)?

Comment: @soon в данном случае - у меня 2 питона, один из них явно лишний. Все должно решаться гораздо проще.

Comment: Явно питон Вы ставили самостоятельно (поскольку он из исходников). Это значит, он Вам был зачем-то нужен. Если в нем больше нет необходимости - его можно смело удалить. Решений существует много, какое выбирать - решать только Вам. Я бы предпочел `virtualenv`.

Comment: Из исходников более новая версия, я бы оставил его. virtualenv не для этого же сделан.

Comment: `virtualenv` служит для того, чтобы не смешивать разные версии питона и библиотек. Если Вы хотите оставить версию из исходников, то Вам нужно удалить старую и переставить библиотеки с использованием встроенного модуля `pip` (см. мое сообщение выше).

Comment: И теперь мы возвращаемся к началу: **как мне снести старую версию (или по крайней мере переверсти все линки на новую)?** :)

Comment: Дак как ставили - так и сносите, в чём проблема то? Вы ведь даже не написали ни дистрибутив, ни откуда исходники взяли, ни чем собирали, собирали ли пакет, выполнили checkinstal или make install. От этого же много зависит. Если checkinstall - у вас пакет и удаляйте его менеджером пакетов, если make install - он равномерно размазался у вас по системе вне менеджера пакетов - т.е. либо скрипт удаления, если таковой есть, либо ручками идёте собирать по системе эти самые размазанные файлы. Поподробнее расскажите чего вы там наустанавливали из исходников.

Comment: @SmitJohnth: *как мне снести старую версию* — правильнее всего будет задать **новый** вопрос по этому поводу.

Comment: @FeroxTL дистрибутив указан. Из исходников через make install, разве можно как-то по-другому? Остальное не помню.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin этот вопрос было бы правильно задать на superuser, которого на русском нет.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, вопрос о том, как удалить старую версию пакета? на мой взгляд, вполне укладывается в тематику этого сайта. только это уже **другой** вопрос и по правилам *.so, должен быть задано **отдельно**, а не в виде комментария к сущестующему вопросу.

Comment: @soon, пожалуйста, соберите написанное вами в виде ответа. если по какой-то причине вы не хотите получать баллы репутации эа этот ответ, его можно отметить «общим».

Comment: Создал. Тогда этот вопрос решен.

Comment: checkinstall собирает пакет и устанавливает в систему уже как deb, а make install делает вас менеджером пакетов и ставит в обход. Соответственно удалить deb то проще простого - dpkg -l и ищешь нужный, а вот после make install удалять его надо самостоятельно. Изредка есть make uninstall скрипт. В общем удачи

Comment: @FeroxTL но это официальные рекомендации со страницы питона! Я просто хочу понять - что я сделал не так? Или оно был изначально поломанным?

Comment: Потому что эти рекомендации - единственное рабочее решение на любом дистрибутиве. Вам такое в любой статье напишут, потому что для того, чтобы попробовать работает оно или нет - этого достаточно - копируешь нужные команды в консоль и всё работает. В отличие от сборки пакетов, да ещё и под конкретный дистрибутив - набор команд может отличаться.

Comment: @FeroxTL а перезапись линков работает разве не в любом дистрибутиве? Алсо, что мешало сделать доки для линупса и для всех юникс-лайков? Так как правильно устанавливать, чтобы не надо было руками ничего делать?

Comment: Да можно линки править, вот только пути у каждого дистрибутива могут быть разные. Та же сборка из репозитория pillow, например, не работает в убунте т.к. часть либ лежит не в /usr/lib/, а в /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/. Сделать для всех версий доки не получится - ради интереса сходи на distrowatch, глянь сколько их. Наиболее правильно ставить пакеты исключительно из официального репозитория, касаемо компиляции - надо читать доки по каждому дистру отдельно.

Comment: @FeroxTL но подожди, туда их ведь раскидывает make скрипт, так в чем проблема эти пути запомнить? Т.е. задача принципиально решаемая. "Наиболее правильно ставить пакеты исключительно из официального репозитория" - а что делать если там старая версия? "надо читать доки по каждому дистру отдельно." - и где мне взять доки по конпеляции конкретной программы под конкретный дистрибутив?

Comment: make скрипт ничего не знает про менеджер пакетов, то же самое верно и наоборот. Почему всё это не интегрировать в make? Потому что KISS. Если версия уж ну совсем старая, то есть сторонние репозитории, например, nginx держит свой. У debian-based есть ppa. Можно и самому собрать, кто ж мешает, но обновлять потом тоже руками придётся. Не enterprise-way, там вообще всё полежавшее любят.По поводу каждого отдельного дистрибутива не скажу - мало этим занимался

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [Debian Python Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/Python#Deviations_from_upstream), директория `dist-packages` используется, если Вы ставили Python из репозитория. Если Вы собирали Python из исходников, вместо `dist-packages` будет использоваться директория `site-packages`, чтобы нивелировать возможные конфликты между версиями Python. Оригинальная цитата:

> `dist-packages` instead of `site-packages`. Third party Python software
>   installed from Debian packages goes into `dist-packages`, not
>   `site-packages`. This is to reduce conflict between the system Python,
>   and any from-source Python build you might install manually.

#### Таким образом, существует несколько путей решения данной проблемы:

1. Использовать [`virtualenv`](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) для управления несколькими версиями Python на одной машине (строго говоря, virtualenv не управляет версиями Python, но с помощью этой программы можно разграничить использование различных версий Python).
2. Явно указывать исполняемый файл Python с необходимой версией.
3. Расширить `sys.path`, включив в него путь до директории с требуемыми библиотеками.
4. Дублировать необходимые пакеты в требуемую версию интерпретатора. Начиная с версии [Python 2.7.9](https://docs.python.org/2/installing/#key-terms) ([Python 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/#key-terms)), в стандартную поставку входит менеджер пакетов `pip`. Пример использования: `python -m pip install <pkg_name>`.
5. Радикальный способ - удалить лишнюю версию Python.

#### Полезные ссылки:

1. [SO: What's the difference between dist-packages and site-packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9388115/1532460)
2. [SU: How to globally modify the default PYTHONPATH (sys.path)?](https://superuser.com/a/247649/424804)