# Есть два питона, как удалить / удалить ссылки на лишний?

Tags: python, debian

[Оригинальный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/439328/python-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-dist-packages)

Есть питон 2.7.10 поставленный из исходников (compile && make && make install) и 2.7.3, взявшийся хз откуда. Похоже на то, что `pip` вызываемый из консоли - от одного питона, а `python` - от другого. Как удалить одну (желательно, более старую) версию питона или по крайней мере сделать так, чтобы все ссылки указывали на нее?

Как вообще могло так получиться, что перезаписались ссылки на python, но не на pip?

Я нуб в линуксе, просьба обьяснять подробно. Заранее спасибо.

Debian

Comment: Чтобы узнать, где находится конкретный питон, используйте команду `which python`, `which pip`.

Comment: @NickVolynkin предположим, узнал, что теперь?

Comment: не знаю ) Что знал — тем поделился. Это хотя бы позволяет убедиться, что они разные.

Comment: @NickVolynkin см. оригинальный вопрос.

Comment: @NickVolynkin используйте `type python` в интерактивном случае или `command -v python` в скриптах, чтобы найти исполняемый файл, запускаемый командой. В общем случае, единственный способ узнать что запустится это запустить команду. Подробнее [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/1321)

Answer (score 3):

скорее всего, *python 2.7.3* установлен по зависимостям из репозитория. и удалить его без **грубейшего** вмешательства в пакетную систему — нельзя.

да и ни к чему.

что именно запускается при вызове программы `python`, можно узнать с помощью программы `which` (вывод приведённых команд может отличаться в вашей системе — выполните их самостоятельно, чтобы узнать точно):

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

в моей системе вообще-то это *symlink* (из пакета *python-minimal*), указывающий на `/usr/bin/python2.7` (из пакета *python2.7-minimal*) но в данном случае это несущественно: ведь вы скомпилировали и установили другую версию *python*-а.

установили вы её, скорее всего (потому что действовали «по умолчанию») в каталог `/usr/local/bin`. а вот под каким именем — это смотрите сами в этом каталоге. вероятно, что-нибудь вроде `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.

для того, чтобы по имени `python` выполнялся именно этот бинарник, вам достаточно создать *symlink* («ссылку-синоним») на него в том же каталоге, но под именем `python`:

```
$ sudo ln -s python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

в результате выполнения этой команды будет создана «ссылка-синоним» `/usr/local/bin/python`, указывающая на `/usr/local/bin/python2.7`.

а благодаря тому, что в переменной окружения `PATH` каталог `/usr/local/bin` перечислен (по умолчанию) **раньше** каталога `/usr/bin`, по имени `python` будет запускаться именно `/usr/local/bin/python`, а не `/usr/bin/python`.

проверьте с помощью программы `which`:

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
```

---

по поводу программы `pip` — почти всё то же самое, за исключением того, что, скорее всего, удаление пакета, из которого она установлена (вероятно, *python-pip*), вряд ли «потянет» за собой удаление ещё множества других пакетов (как в случае попытки удаления пакета, содержащего `/usr/bin/python` — мне `apt-get` предложил удалить 114 пакетов).

---

**справка**

в дистрибутивах, основанных на *debian gnu/linux* (*ubuntu*, *mint* и т.д. и т.п.), использующих пакетную систему *deb*, узнать, какому именно пакету принадлежит тот или иной файл (если, конечно, принадлежит хоть какому-то), можно, например, так:

```
$ dpkg -S /полный/путь/к/файлу
```

Comment: "для того, чтобы по имени python выполнялся именно этот бинарник..." - update-alternatives со скомпилированными бинарниками не сработает?

Comment: "скорее всего, python 2.7.3 установлен по зависимостям из репозитория. и удалить его без грубейшего вмешательства в пакетную систему — нельзя." - ок, а проапгрейдить его до 2.7.10 можно?

Comment: @Etki, нет: `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for python` — в *wheezy* и *jessie* (то, что сейчас «под рукой»).

Comment: @SmitJohnth, не имеет смысла — вы ведь **уже** собрали и установили версию 2.7.10 (в обход пакетной системы дистрибутива).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin я поставил второй питон, который сейчас конфликтует. А проапгрейдить без конфликтов нельзя? Т.е. в винде я сделал бы так - удалил бы оба, если один трогать нельзя  - попытался бы один удалить, а один корректно проапгрейдить. А что с тем который из исходников? Он как-то косячно встал?

Comment: @SmitJohnth, что именно вы подразумеваете под словосочетанием «второй питон»? что именно вы хотите «проапгрейдить»?

Comment: @SmitJohnth, *Он как-то косячно встал?* — извините, но мне отсюда не видно, что и как «встало» в **вашей** системе. одно могу сказать точно: «установив» (а, фактически, просто разбросав файлы по файловой системе) «что-то» в обход пакетного менеджера, вы создали благодатную почву для последующих **вполне возможных** проблем.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin всем видно, что ссылка на python перезаписалась, а на пип - нет, это я и имею в виду под "косячно встало". Я выполнял рекомендации по установке питона из исходников как бы даже не с оффсайта питона. Ок, а как надо ставить правильно последнюю версию 2.7?

Comment: @SmitJohnth, если это ваша персональная домашняя/рабочая/разработческая машина, то не стоит переживать по этому поводу. если же это сервер, за работу которого кто-то несёт ответственность, то я бы на месте этого «кото-то», как минимум, прочитал бы вам «долгую лекцию, перемежающуюся [не]литературными эпитетами».

Comment: @SmitJohnth: *Ок, а как надо ставить правильно последнюю версию 2.7* — правильно вопрос звучит: «как предпочтительнее ставить новые версии программ, отсутствующие в репозиториях дистрибутива икс», и он заслуживает в ответ большой обзорной статьи, по-моему, совершенно не укладывающейся ни в рамки вопроса-ответа, ни, тем более, в рамки комментариев на этом сайте. собственно, по этому поводу статей написан ваго и маленькая тележка. воспользуйтесь. пожалуйста, любой удобной поисковой системой.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, *а на пип - нет* — прочитайте, пожалуйста, предпоследний абзац в моём ответе. он как раз и посвещён программе `pip`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin он посвящен тому, как руками поправить ссылки, оставив оба питона, правильно? Если удалить пип от 2.7.3, это ведь не добавит автоматически ссылку на 2.7.10?

Comment: @SmitJohnth, *в винде я сделал бы так* — в дистрибутивах операционной системы *ms/windows* **нет** ни репозиториев с программами, ни пакетного менеджера. у пакетного менеджмента, несомненно, есть свои недостатки, которые, по моему скромному мнению, с огромаднейшим запасом перекрываются его достоинствами.

Comment: @SmitJohnth, *Если удалить пип от 2.7.3, это ведь не добавит автоматически ссылку на 2.7.10?* — да, не добавит. впрочем, по поводу того, что функциональность программы `pip` «встроена» в `python`, вам писали ещё в комментариях к вашему предыдущему вопросу.